# unsafe implementation of WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler

Tags: react-native, android-security, react-native-webview

I received the warning you see in the below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPuwT.png)

Your app is using an unsafe implementation of WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

Although we wrote the following code for onReceviedErrorhandler on RNCWebViewManager.java from React-Native-Webview. The problem still persists. We will be very happy if you help.

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView webView, final SslErrorHandler handler, final SslError error) {
        handler.cancel();

        int code = error.getPrimaryError();
        String failingUrl = error.getUrl();
        String description = "";

        // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/SslError.html
        switch (code) {
          case SslError.SSL_DATE_INVALID:
            description = "The date of the certificate is invalid";
            break;
          case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
            description = "The certificate has expired";
            break;
          case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
            description = "Hostname mismatch";
            break;
          case SslError.SSL_INVALID:
            description = "A generic error occurred";
            break;
          case SslError.SSL_MAX_ERROR:
            description = "The number of different SSL errors.";
            break;
          case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
            description = "The certificate is not yet valid";
            break;
          case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
            description = "The certificate authority is not trusted";
            break;
          default: 
            description = "Unknown SSL Error";
            break;
        }

        this.onReceivedError(
          webView,
          code,
          description,
          failingUrl
        );
    }
```

Platform - React Native
It's from a 3d party library - React-Native-Webview